# detect that the vector in the any opposite directions to the current

Tags: vector-spaces

I little bit stuck with quiz -
I have vector 'a' and need function which will be checking any other vector, what that vector in negative y'(relatively to vector 'a')
I draw simple image below to try explain what I want. On this image all green vectors have to return TRUE and blue FALSE

[image]

for example: if I have vector 'a'(3,2), vector (1,3) return FALSE, but vector (-2,2) return TRUE
how can I check vectors to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that by using this function:

$f_a(x)=\text{TRUE}$ if $\cos(a,x)>0$

and $f_a(x)=\text{FALSE}$ if $\cos(a,x)<0$.

It's so because $\cos(a,x)>0$ if the angle between a and x is less that 90 degree and $\cos(a,x)<0$ if the angle between a and x is more that 90 degree.